# I'm new to d3.js and i want to do a continous transition but not working

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to loop my transition repeatedly but i dont understand whats wrong with the code.

I've tried using ".on('end', repeat) but its not working.
here is my code...

var edges = d3.selectAll('.edge');

```
    var indexAndEdge = [];
    edges.each(function(d, i) {

    var thisEdgeCount = this.id.substring(4)
    indexAndEdge.push({ //push index you are at, the edge count worked out above and the id
        index: i,
        count: thisEdgeCount,
        id: this.id
    })
    })

    indexAndEdge.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.count - b.count;
    });

    var count = 0; //set count to 0

    function timer() {
    setTimeout(function(d) {
        if (count < indexAndEdge.length) { //if we havent gone through all edges
        d3.select('#' + indexAndEdge[count].id)
        .transition()
        .duration(4000)
        .style('opacity', 0)
        .transition()
        .duration(5000)
        .style('opacity', 1)
        .transition()
        .duration(6000)
        .style('opacity', 2) //select current id from array
        count++; //increment count
        timer(); //call timer again
        } 
        else {
        console.log('repeat') //end
        }
    }, 1000)
    ;
    }
    timer(); //call timer to show paths one by one
</script>
```

i expect the edges to continue forever

Comment: can you create a codepen for your problem

Comment: I am not familiar with codepen?? any idea on how to go about it?

Comment: [codepen_embed height="265" theme_id="0" slug_hash="QWLrRmX" default_tab="html,result" user="Thinker95"]See the Pen <a href='https://codepen.io/Thinker95/pen/QWLrRmX/'>QWLrRmX</a> by Pelz Thinker (<a href='https://codepen.io/Thinker95'>@Thinker95</a>) on <a href='https://codepen.io'>CodePen</a>.[/codepen_embed]

Comment: Can't access the codepen. You just create an account on codepen [link](https://codepen.io/). Jsut create your pen there. save it and then share the URL of that page.

Comment: okay. thank you. be right back

Comment: here is the link to the codepen... https://codepen.io/Thinker95/pen/GRKdaxB

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to draw. Can you explain a little more what is it that you want to do?

Comment: Okay, i just included the svg code in the codepen now. i want the arrows to move continuously without stopping and also include a easeBounce transition. kindly check the codepen again here https://codepen.io/Thinker95/pen/GRKdaxB